# getting vector from an Arc Mutex

Tags: rust

So I have this code:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex}; 

fn main() {
    
    let array = vec!("test", "work", "please");
    let test = Arc::new(Mutex::new(array));
    
    let getter = test.lock().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", getter);
    
    for item in getter {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}
```

it throws an error saying:

```
error[E0277]: `MutexGuard<'_, Vec<&str>>` is not an iterator
  --> src/main.rs:11:17
   |
11 |     for item in getter {
   |                 ^^^^^^ `MutexGuard<'_, Vec<&str>>` is not an iterator
   |
   = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `MutexGuard<'_, Vec<&str>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `MutexGuard<'_, Vec<&str>>`
```

Which, okay fine. But I am able to do `let getter = test.lock().unwrap().len();` and that gets the length correctly. So why does it know its an array in the second case but not the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getter` is a `MutexGuard` which implements `Deref<Target = Vec<&str>>`. When you call a method on it like `.len()`, it's automatically dereferenced into the `Vec` because there's no `.len()` method on `MutexGuard`. The same is not done automatically by a `for` loop. You can either force a manual dereference:

```
for item in &*getter {
```

or you can call `.iter()` on it which automatically dereferences it:

```
for item in getter.iter() {
```

Code:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let array = vec!["test", "work", "please"];
    let test = Arc::new(Mutex::new(array));

    let getter = test.lock().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", getter);

    for item in &*getter {
        println!("{}", item);
    }

    for item in getter.iter() {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e9ec0193e650b5000db167c01d9116c6)

Answer (score 2):

The `.len()` access works because of [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html) (as the `MutexGuard` implements `Deref`), but this does not apply when checking if a value implements `Iterator` or `IntoIterator`.

You can manually deref-and-reborrow to make that work:

```
    for item in &*getter {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
```